# Creating text string in google script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, concatenation

I'm trying to do what I thought was basic script.  but alas i'm struggling.

In Column C I am trying to create a string of Column D & Column E with a space in the middle.  as a formula I would use

=D18&" "&E18

as code I have

```
{function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("CP");
var cell = sheet.getRange("C:C");
cell.setFormula("=D:D&E:E");}
```

which does combine the two cells but without a space.  is this at all possible.  It needs to be done in script because I have third party services connected to google sheets where the data comes in but the formula does not carry down.

Thanks Dan

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
cell.setFormula('=Arrayformula(D:D&" "&E:E)')
```

Comment: I tried this and although formula was brought through correctly as an array it errored because it was referencing itself

Comment: You can not use a formula referencing columns in those columns itself. The output should be okay when entered in column F (or any other column).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function cde(){
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('CP');
  var rg=sh.getRange(1,3,sh.getLastRow(),3);
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  for(var i=0;i<vA.length;i++){
    vA[i][0]=String(vA[i][1]) + " " + String(vA[i][2]);
  }
  rg.setValues(vA);
}
```